# how can a click handler for a class within a class be implemented?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am putting a menu option for each row in a table like this.
[image]

The menu option class is "toggle-wrap" and the table row class is "text-left". this is my menu option click handler

```
    (function($){

           $( '.toggle' ).click(function(){
             var target = $( this ).data( 'menu' );

             $( '#' + target ).toggleClass( 'menu--open' );
           });

        })(jQuery);
```

the handler works when the menu option is by itself but when I added the menu option class into the table row class in the code below i can't get the click handler to work.

```
  <td class="text-left" >

                     <div class="toggle-wrap">
                        <button class="toggle" data-menu="settings"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i><span>Settings</span></button>
                        <ul class="menu menu--toggle" id="settings">
                          <li class="menu__item">Edit My Profile<i class="fa fa-user"></i></li>
                          <li class="menu__item">Edit Account Details<i class="fa fa-list"></i></li>
                          <li class="menu__item">Need Help<i class="fa fa-support"></i></li>
                          <li class="menu__item">Sign Out<i class="fa fa-lock"></i></li>
                        </ul>
                      </div>


                  </td>
```

what am I doing wrongly?

Comment: Do you have a binding on the toggle-wrap for click as well?  Try passing 'e' into your toggle click handler and doing e.stopPropagation() to prevent the event from bubbling up to that element if they click the toggle button.

Comment: It is working fine : https://jsfiddle.net/wm8zq58x/

Comment: your code is working fine as per your given question.

Comment: It is working fine so it seems like menu is being created dynamically. Try using `$(document).on('click', '.toggle', handler)` instead of `$('.toggle').click(handler)`

Comment: @RahulJain thank you that fixed it! I can mark it as answered it you post it as answer instead of a comment. What is the difference between the two $(document).on('click', '.toggle', handler) instead of $('.toggle').click(handler)

Comment: Try a google search for Event bubbling and `jquery.on` method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The menu you are creating is generated dynamically so it is being created after the javascript call which is attaching event listener to `.toggle` elements

What you can do is make the use of event bubbling. Try some container element which is statically present at the time javascript call is running which is attaching the event listener and which you are sure will contain the `.toggle` element. Attach the event listener to this container using `jquery.on` and put the selector `.toggle` in selectors argument :

`$(container).on('click', '.toggle', handler)`

**How it works:**

On clicking `.toggle` element, the click event bubbles up i.e. its parent elements will get to know about this event. Once it reaches to the container element, our handler gets called.